# What does the argument -ab in ffmpeg mean?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-converter

From someone I received a batch file that can do ffmpeg conversion using 2 command arguments. Let's say the file is called `convert.sh` and only contains this line:

`ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 36000 -i "$1" -ar 8000 -ab 16K -ac 1 -y "$2"`

I call it as follows:

`sh convert.sh inputfile.wav outputfile.wav`

In the ffmpeg documentation, I can find what all arguments mean, except for `-ab`. I guess `16K` is its value. But I have no idea what it does. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-ab argument means audio bitrate

Comment: Thanks! So is that the same as `-r`?

Comment: @Lewistrick Have you looked at the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for the `ffmpeg` tool?

Answer (score 4):

-ar- set the audio sampling frequency

-ac- Set the number of audio channels

-ab- Set the audio bitrate

for more info visit this [link](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)